# What kind of generator do i need to run a 1.5 or 2 ton Air Conditioner?

Tags: power, ac, generator

I am planning to purchase a single AC that would operate on my Diesel generator. My Generator is a 5kVA , 8 HP air cooled one. I want to know that If I have to run only one AC on the generator shall I install a 2 Ton Split AC or a 1.5 Ton Split AC?

Also I Want to know the diesel consumption by the generator per hour.

Comment: Read the electrical rating on the AC units and you should be able to work it out.

Comment: There are two things that are being mentioned . Power Consumption and cooling capacity. Which one determines the value I am interested in? for an Air conditioner of 1.5 ton ,the power consumption is 1438 wattt and cooling capacity is 5050W

Comment: How many watts is 5kVA? You don't need to answer - just think about it.

Comment: It's an 8HP model. 1 HP=746 Watts. So it's wattage is 5768 watt.

Comment: @Apoorv That is wrong. No way is a 5 KVA generator going to produce 5768 watts,

Comment: What would be the output Wattage ? I am not a electronic guy . need help in this please.

Comment: I calculated now with this website https://www.macfarlanegenerators.com.au/power-calculator.php and it comes to be 4000W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cooling capacity is not relevant. The power consumed is important, but you also need to know the current. AC motors need more current than the minimum required for the power consumption. You also need to make sure you have the right voltage and whether you need single-phase or three phase. The KVA for a motor that consumes 1438 watts will probably be between 1.7 and 2.6 KVA.

Watts = VA X Power Factor It is customary for engine generator sets to be designed for 0.8 maximum power factor so 5000 VA X 0.8 = 4000 W would be expected.

Comment: These are the details I could find for the AC . A 1.5 ton one Operating Current 6.35 A
Power Requirement AC 230 V, 50 Hz
Power Consumption 1438 W ... you can refer the link here and help me out ?  http://www.flipkart.com/voltas-1-5-ton-5-star-split-ac-white/p/itmdvrkcmsdyxmfe?pid=ACNDVRJFG5CBXQTZ&al=SEEto%2BXx1ypZKq7IgfhE5MldugMWZuE7sHPMhtl4IOqQw9ucgn%2BDfIk%2FAp3XWjJQNA40%2BxiWIis%3D&ref=L%3A-648177335033313899&srno=p_4&otracker=from-search

Comment: 6.35 A X 230 V = 1461 VA Less than I thought, but perhaps not surprising. The motor is probably a capacitor run type. The capacitor must be sufficient to correct the power factor to 0.98. Everything seems to indicate your generator has plenty of capacity.

Comment: One last thing I would like to ask is can it run 2 AC units simultaneously? Provided no other appliance is there except an inverter which is charging from the Generator

Comment: I would say most likely, but don't have them start at the same time.  This is a home improvienent question that belongs on diy.stackexchange, hence some of the snark you are seeing. Although you are also asking us to do really basic thinking for you, as if you are looking for an official blessing, that's not what we do in either SE.

Answer (score 2):

> Power Consumption and cooling capacity. Which one determines the value I am interested in? For an Air conditioner of 1.5 ton ,the power consumption is 1438 wattt and cooling capacity is 5,050 W.

Your air conditioning unit works on the principle of a "heat pump". In your case electricity is used to drive the pump. According to the rating plate it will consume 1,438 W of energy while pumping 5,050 W of heat. It is common to quote the coefficient of performance (CoP) for heat pumps as \$ \frac {heat~moved}{electrical~input} = \frac {5050}{1438} = 3.5 \$ which is reasonably good.

The generator is rated at 5 kVA. For a purely resistive load 1 VA = 1 W but your air-con unit will be an inductive load so we'll need to derate the generator by about 20% when converting to watts. Let's go for 4kW.

Your 1438 W AC unit (let's call it 1.5 kW) will load your generator by approximately \$ \frac {1.5~kW}{4~kW} = 38\% \$. It should be fine.

Comment: I would like to ask you about a 2 Ton AC . Please see the link below and tell me that would a 2 TON AC shall be fine ? http://www.flipkart.com/voltas-2-tons-5-star-split-ac-nano-silver/p/itmehh9mkxuhbxqw?pid=ACNEHH9MVNJBPTGD&al=SEEto%2BXx1yoILvwZ0meqdMldugMWZuE7sHPMhtl4IOpNHNic%2B23m14CwabY2ZuC8GjX%2FnTsaKY8%3D&ref=L%3A-2683286268643226222&srno=p_5&otracker=from-search    .... for the generator specification , the second one  from (Air Cooled , Single Phase ) can be considered . Please have a look    http://www.topland-india.com/products/genset/htm/genset_24.htm

Comment: Sorry, but I have shown you how to work it out. Time for you to do your own calculations.

Comment: The heading of the generator chart says "1.0 unity power factor" and the chart says 5.0 (5.0) kVA (kW) so you have plenty of power. The AC page states only watts, not kVA or amps, not a good presentation of specs, but at 1774 watts, you should have plenty of capacity. You need some spare capacity to handle starting current also, but the generator probably has what you need.

Comment: @CharlesCowie the 1.5 ton AC shows this 
Operating Current 6.35 A
Power Requirement AC 230 V, 50 Hz
Power Consumption 1438 W

Comment: @transistor sir , one last thing. how much load is ok for the generator ? your current calculation comes for 38% . what about 60% load ? Is it heavy enough for the generator ?